# ubuntu 22.04 LTS No power menu Icon on taskbar

Tags: unity, virtualbox, icons, ssd, shutdown

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop as a vm. When I launched it everything seemed to be working until I tried to shutdown the vm. There is no menu icon on the taskbar to access the shutdown option. I have to go in to the terminal and issue the shutdown command to get it to properly close.

Is there a way to add the icon for the shutdown options or is this a new feature of the desktop?

This is on a Lenovo E595 taptop running windows 10 Pro.
It has 32GB RAM, 1TB SSD C, and 2TB SSD D. Both drives are roughly 0.75% empty.

I am using Oracle Virtual Box  for vm management.
The vm is Ubuntu desktop 22.04 LTS

Thank you Dave for the link! I feel like an idiot now.
I did not realize that the power off / log off options were moved under the battery icon. I saw the down arrow for the power off / log off options was gone and assumed the whole thing was gone.

Again Thank You for the link!

Comment: This should help: https://fostips.com/disable-power-off-log-out-sub-menu-ubuntu-20-10-gnome/

Comment: @Scott__, you don't have the system tray? If so, it could be that you toggled it off with the theme you selected or the related extension. You can should be able to find the settings in tweaks and/or extension manager.